# Find relationship between X and Y

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Given:

$X_1 = 100, Y_1 = 64$

$X_2 = 70, Y_2 = 34$

$X_3 = 50, Y_3 = 14$

I need to find the $Y = F(X)$ formula.

I can see that $X_2 - X_1 = Y_2 - Y_1$, but $X_2/X_1 \neq Y_2/Y_1$.

P.S. This is not homework, i'm trying to work out some CSS properties which affect each other, my math is just terrible. Thank you!

Comment: I believe $Y=X-36$ works.

Comment: Why I always complicate things and ignore simple operations :D ?

Comment: It's a good learning moment though! If changing $X$ always causes a proportional change in $Y$, then the equation you're looking for is linear, $Y=mX+b$. In this case, the "proportional" change in $Y$ is exactly the same change as the change in $X$, which is why $m=1$ in this case.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you very much. This makes so much sense now!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. Simple one is to : pass a circle through the 3 points and find its equation